# Make ODBC connection between Windows 8 on VMware Fusion to MySql instances on OS X host

Tags: windows-8, mysql, osx-mavericks, vmware-fusion

I am trying to create an ODBC connection (64-bit) from a Windows 8 installed on VMware Fusion, to a mysql instance install on the host OS (OS X Mavericks).  Connection not successful.  What am I missing?

Diagnosis:

- mysql (5.6.17 Homebrew) instance running on OS X (localhost:3306)
- can connect to database using Sequel Pro
- can ping host by name and IP
- VM's network in 'bridged' mode
- MySQL ODBC 5.2 driver; tried ANSI and Unicode variants; both failed

ODBC settings:

[image]

Error:

[image]

** edit **

From [Connecting to a MySQL database on Mac from a VMWare fusion Virtual Machine](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60035/connecting-to-a-mysql-database-on-mac-from-a-vmware-fusion-virtual-machine), I decided to remove the `--bind-address=127.0.0.1` from the `homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist` file.

After a restart, I'm getting this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101243/error-1130-hy000-host-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server), I issued this command in Sequel Plus:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

then:

```
SELECT host FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'root';
```

results:

```
%
127.0.0.1
::1
Foobar.local
localhost
```

This fixed the problem.

**Is there a more-secure way to configure this?**